# mod_rewrite infite loop

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, infinite-loop

i have Apache 2.2 and 3 virtual hosts on it and a mod_rewrite infinite lopp isssue i cannot resolve. Apache is in my company LAN on the 192.168.1.228 IP address. 2 virtual hosts work perfectly. The third makes problems. My network admin created a subdomain to point to that 192.168.1.228. The Virtual Host is configured this way:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.228>
   DocumentRoot "C:/Apache/htdocs/stansrodowiska"
   ServerName giostube.mycompany.local

  LimitInternalRecursion 1000

  <Directory "C:/Apache/htdocs/stansrodowiska">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
      AllowOverride None
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all

      RewriteEngine on

      RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|upload|css|download|assets|js|nfos|robots\.txt)
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /stansrodowiska/index.php/$1 [L]

  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

If i access this website from my lan over the address: http://giostube.mycompany.local/ i get an

```
403 Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /stansrodowiska/index.php/stansrodowiska/index.php/stansrodowiska/index.php/stansrodowiska/index.php/stansrodowiska/index.php/stansrodowiska/index.php/stansrodowiska/index.php......... on this server
```

The /stansrodowiska/index.php/ is of course repeated much more often i think to around 2048 chars which is the HTTP POST maximum. 
Strange thing is that exactly the same mod_rewrite rules work on an other preconfigured WAMP environment (Vertrigo).
Underneath there is a Codeigniter 1.7.2 application.

Is the error within the mod_rewrite rules or do i have to search elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /stansrodowiska/index.php/$1 [L]
```

To:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Half ok - in the adressbar of my browser after i go to:  http://giostube.mycompany.local/ it converts the url to: http://192.168.1.228/stansrodowiska/gios/index. The part after the IP is ok. I dont know why it shows me the IP and not the adress: http://giostube.mycompany.local/stansrodowiska/gios/index ? Second thing: it redirects me not to the correct application but to an other virtual host with a different application. But for now i got to little chars left tu put here the code of the second VHost. I'll put it in another comment.

Comment: In case of mod_rewrite that was the right solution so i'm accepting. The rest was my error and i fixed it.